# ng-repeat select with disabled options

Tags: angularjs

I have Array

```
vm.helpersIterator = [ ] //store new <select>-s
```

and Object like this

```
vm.helpersObj = {
    2014: {name: 'test', selected: true},  
    1290: {name: 'test1', selected: false},
}
```

html:

```
<select name="helper" class="form-control"
   ng-repeat="helper in vm.helpersIterator track by $index">
     <option value="">- Select helper -</option>
     <option ng-repeat="(uid, helper) in vm.helpersObj"
             ng-value="uid"
             ng-selected="helper.selected">
             {{helper.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

I'll can push many `<select>`-s in vm.helpersIterator array.
But I need to disable options which already been selected.

You can see my attached picture for understand.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: you wish to disable/remove items which have been selected in a different dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-disabled` will do what you want.

Here is a plunkr with a working example, similar to yours.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YLXFVbndqAaPV4mMsynR?p=preview

I also used `ng-change` for setting the selectedOption as `selected`

Comment: Thank for your answer , you save my time ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but, it seems like you'd like to conditionally add the `disabled` attribute for any object in your `helpersObj` array that has a `selected` property of `true`?

If that's that case, you can simply swap out your `ng-selected` for [`ng-disabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
<option ng-repeat="(uid, helper) in vm.helpersObj"
        ng-value="uid"
        ng-disabled="helper.selected">
        {{helper.name}}
</option>
```