# ng-repeat with disabled options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help me to resolve this problem.

I have the object

```
vm.users = {
   helpers: {
      name: 'John Smith',
      uid: 2094
   },
   foremen: {
      name: 'Michael Duglas',
      uid: 2389
   }
}
```

User can create a `select` which contains foremans, helpers and grouped by role names.
When user choose foreman or helper, other `select`s should be updated and hide already selected foremen or helpers.

You can see my attached [picture](https://yadi.sk/i/JIJU1HxaoaXeD) for more information.

I find [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733574/ng-repeat-select-with-disabled-options) from this question but this is not complete.
I want to get working solution.

Comment: You want to get a working solution? Where is your code? Do you have a plunkr? What have your tried? What is your problem?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for reply , I don't have code, and get working solution